# Using the Charge plugin to store customer credit card info, how to re-validate the credit card when customer submits order

Tags: plugin-charge, stripe

We able to use charge plugin to store customer credit information as "Customers" in Stripe, however, "Customers" information might be saved awhile ago, we would like to re-verify the credit card information is still valid when the customer submits an order. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any luck Angela? I'm trying to used saved cards for transactions, and I'm not able to find any documentation on how to do this using Charge.

Comment: We finally need to charge a customer $0.5 and then refund $0.5 to verify the card still valid before the customer submits an order.